# Check for correct answer (quiz) using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a picture quiz with a single input field for each image. I need a way to check if the value entered into the input field matches the correct answer and if it does, perform a few operations like add/remove a few CSS classes and increase the score count. And I need this to be done in real time using AJAX.

This is the pseudo-code for the functionality that I want...

```
if input value == correct answer {
    some jQuery to add/remove a few classes
    some PHP (I assume) to add 1 to the score count
} else {
    some jQuery to add/remove a few classes
}
```

However, how do I get the value of the input field in real time? Do I still use PHP Post to get the value? What AJAX do I need to do this without a page refresh?

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I'm okay with PHP but very little experience with AJAX. Thank you.

Comment: you should first try by yourself with html / jquery, and if you have issues post your code here for help

Comment: Surely this cannot be done without AJAX? I am asking what is the best way to get the value entered? If someone could answer this then I might be able to at least give it a try.

Comment: The only way to mix execution of PHP code in a Javascript sequence is to make a call to your server. Wether this is synchronous or not is a matter of design.

Comment: you give very few info, so you get very few help. it's depends of the kind of question, if the answers really has to be checked in server side or if hidding the answer in js can do the thing, etc...

Comment: Lack of info is due to lack of experience with this type of development. Thanks for your help though you have pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

yes this can be done with AJAX, and with jquery (which is not the same).

You can get input string with `$("#input_id").val()` , show a simple error message with `alert("my message")`, and use the `onchange` event. see also what is `e.preventDefault()` to make the form not submitable if all is not correct

If you want to check if datas are correct with a php request, that's also possible with `$.ajax()`

See jquery documentation on the web for further information about all theses functions

Comment: Apologies for the vague question - you've done well to provide the info you have from what I described. Appreciate the help, this will at least get me heading in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful for anyone else, this is how I achieved my original goal. Contrary to what I first thought, this can all be done using JS and does not require PHP or AJAX to update in real time.

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    if (($(this).val() == 'test') {
        //Stuff
    } else {
        //Other Stuff
    };
});
```

The .keyup() function is what allows this to work in real-time, as it is called whenever a key is hit on your keyboard.

Then within this, the .val() function is what is used to check the actual user-entered value of the input field. In this case, if this value equals 'test', then it performs whatever you place in the if statement.

Hope that helps if anyone has stumbled across this question hoping for this answer!